# how to repeat a string in excel with its iteration number?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

suppose I have a cell in excel containing a natural number like 5, I want to repeat a string like "ab" with its iteration number separated by comma in adjacent cell like this: 'ab1,ab2,ab3,ab4,ab5'. is there a none VB method in excel to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following as well using `SEQUENCE()` & `ARRAYTOTEXT()` functions:

[image]

---

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT("ab"&SEQUENCE(,A1))
```

---

Alternatively one can use `TEXTJOIN()` with `SEQUENCE()` if they dont need the white spaces that created using `ARRAYTOTEXT()` function. Courtesy to **[BigBen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9245853/bigben)** Sir for asking to add the alternative, so as to avoid the white spaces.

[image]

---

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,"ab"&SEQUENCE(,A1))
```

---

Comment: I did not know you could concat a string in a sequence like that, very nice.

Comment: Well done, bard and chat gpt failed me. but apparently comma in SEQUENCE function is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MAKEARRAY` function to generate an array of values, and then `TEXTJOIN` to concatenate them together with `,`s:

Formatted formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    ",",
    FALSE,
    MAKEARRAY(
        1, A1,
        LAMBDA(r, c,
            CONCAT("ab", c)
        )
    )
)
```

Single line:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",FALSE,MAKEARRAY(1,A1,LAMBDA(r,c,CONCAT("ab",c))))
```

With comments:

```
=TEXTJOIN(                    # Join strings
    ",",                      # Join with ,
    FALSE,                    # Include empty strings, irrelevant here
    MAKEARRAY(                # Make array to join
        1, A1,                    # One row, =A1 columns
        LAMBDA(r, c,              # Function to make array elements, row and column number as input
            CONCAT("ab", c)       # Array element is concatenation of "ab" and column number
        )
    )
)
```

[image]